# How to join two tables where Columns are not matching in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables and in the select query I need to bring the SUM of the other column but both the tables have some similar data but still in the query output values are not coming fine.

I am using below query :-

**Query 1**

```
select COUNTRY, SUM (BUDGET_SALES) AS BUDGET_SALES

 from ANALYSE.LCM_COMMON_BUDGET_SALES

 WHERE WEEK_START_DATE=@WEEK_COMMENCING_VAR

group by COUNTRY
```

**Query 2**

```
select distinct cntry AS COUNTRY, SUM (B.BUDGET_SALES) AS BUDGET
 from [publish].[LCM_COMMON_HNB_WEEKLY_ACTUAL] A
 
left join ANALYSE.LCM_COMMON_BUDGET_SALES B

ON --A.bnnr=B.BANNER 
A.cntry=B.COUNTRY 
--and A.Week_End=B.WEEK_END_DATE
and A.Week_Commencing=B.WEEK_START_DATE

WHERE A.Week_Commencing=@WEEK_COMMENCING_VAR
group by cntry
```

**Query 1 output**

| COUNTRY | BUDGET_SALES |
| --- | --- |
| MY | 20463355.16 |
| SG | 41095952.67 |

**Query 2 output**

| COUNTRY | BUDGET |
| --- | --- |
| HK | NULL |
| SG | 7767135054.63 |
| ID | NULL |
| MO | NULL |
| MY | 12441719937.28 |

**How can this be fixed so that the Query 2 shows the** `BUDGET` **same as** `BUDGET_SALES`  of Query 1

Sample of table  `[publish].[LCM_COMMON_HNB_WEEKLY_ACTUAL]` :-

| COUNTRY | BANNER | BANNER_DESC | SITE | WEEK_START_DATE | WEEK_END_DATE | BUDGET_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HK | FOOD | LEVEN | 3314 | 2020-11-23 | 2021-01-03 | 13538.40 |
| HK | FOOD | LEVEN | 3126 | 2020-11-23 | 2021-01-03 | 7403.63 |

Sample of table  `ANALYSE.LCM_COMMON_BUDGET_SALES` :-

| COUNTRY | BANNER | Week_Commencing | Week_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HK | HN | 2020-11-23 | 2020-11-29 |
| HK | HN | 2020-11-23 | 2020-11-29 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT :-**

| COUNTRY | SUM_BUDGET | Week_Commencing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MY | 20463355.16 | 2021-01-04 |
| SG | 41095952.67 | 2021-01-04 |

Comment: Having a `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY` in your query infers a flaw; either your `GROUP BY` is incomplete or the `DISTINCT` isn't required.

Comment: As for the question, expected results will help us help you. If you want the `JOIN` the table, then some data must match, as otherwise *what* are you planning to join on

Comment: @Larnu, even I can avoid using Join (although column country, banner, start date, Week end has similar data of other table) and instead can use Union. But using Union also, I am not getting the desired output

Comment: Added Expected output too

Comment: Tried modifying both ```GROUP BY``` and ```DISTINCT``` .Still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely is that your table [publish].[LCM_COMMON_HNB_WEEKLY_ACTUAL] has a different granularity (likely lower) than your table ANALYSE.LCM_COMMON_BUDGET_SALES so this what I would do:

1. Get to the same grain first - Country and Week. You should verify independently that the country weekly budget amounts meet expectations

```
With CountryWeeklyActual as
(
  select Country, WEEK_START_DATE, SUM(BUDGET_SALES) as ActualBudgetSum
  from [publish].[LCM_COMMON_HNB_WEEKLY_ACTUAL]
  where WEEK_START_DATE = @WEEK_COMMENCING_VAR
  group by Country, WEEK_START_DATE
), CountryWeeklyCommon as
(
  select COUNTRY, Week_Commencing, SUM(BUDGET_SALES) as CommonBudgetSum
  from ANALYSE.LCM_COMMON_BUDGET_SALES
  where Week_Commencing = @WEEK_COMMENCING_VAR
  Group by COUNTRY, Week_Commencing 
)
```

2. Join at the same level of granularity

```
select wa.COUNTRY, wa.WEEK_START_DATE, wa.ActualBudgetSum, wc.Week_Commencing, wc.CommonBudgetSum
From CountryWeeklyActual wa 
left join CountryWeeklyCommon wc
on wa.COUNTRY=wc.Country and wa.WEEK_START_DATE=wc.Week_Commencing
```

From here you can decide what fields you need to include.

Comment: Np. Glad to be of assistance.